# Add a button load more below uitableview

Tags: swift, uitableview

I need a solution in swift to add a button below uitableview, how to do it ? do I have to add a custom cell at the end ? or add an another view below uitableview ? I tried to add a view, but I can't see this one.

Comment: both are correct but if you have static height cells you can easily add a view instead of a more cell

Comment: what do you want? Do you want that button to be below the table view or at the end of the view.

Comment: @Sh_Khan static height cells ? or static content elements ?

Comment: @sanjaykmwt Boths are good, but they're a nice solution below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the simplest way to add a `button/CustomView` at the bottom of the `tableView`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: self.tableView.frame.width, height: 40)))
    button.setTitle("Load more", for: .normal)
    button.backgroundColor = .lightGray
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(moreButtonClicked(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = button
}

@objc func moreButtonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
   print("More button clicked, fetch more data!")
}
```